# Validador de CPF JS/Vue

Tags: javascript, funções, vue.js, validação

Estou tentando usar uma função para validar CPF e ao fim dela chamar a função que confere se o campo é requerido e numérico.

Se eu chamar apenas a função `forgotmain`, ocorre tudo certo, mas não valida o CPF. Estou usando `v-btn @click.prevent="validarCPF()"` no HTML para chamar as funções.

```
methods: {
    forgotmain() {
      if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.$router.push("forgotcode");
      } else {
        this.$v.$touch();
      }
    },
    validarCPF(inputCPF) {
      var soma = 0;
      var i;
      var resto;
      var inputCPF = document.getElementById("cpf").value;

      if (inputCPF == "00000000000") return false;
      for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        soma = soma + parseInt(inputCPF.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
      resto = (soma * 10) % 11;

      if (resto == 10 || resto == 11) resto = 0;
      if (resto != parseInt(inputCPF.substring(9, 10))) return false;

      soma = 0;
      for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        soma = soma + parseInt(inputCPF.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
      resto = (soma * 10) % 11;

      if (resto == 10 || resto == 11) resto = 0;
      if (resto != parseInt(inputCPF.substring(10, 11))) return false;
      return true;

      forgotmain();
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao fim da sua função, você está chamando forgotMain da seguinte maneira

```
forgotmain()
```

troque para:

```
this.forgotmain()
```